# Error on VS code when trying to debug TestCafe test

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code, e2e-testing, testcafe

My test.js file contains this row in order to import 'Page' class from page-model.js file:
import Page from './page-model';

When I run test.js through Shell with the command: "npm test", it runs well.

I get an "Unexpected identifier" error when trying to debug my Testcafe test on Visual studio code.
This is the full message:
"

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Page from './page-model';
                                                                 ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

"

```
This are my dependencies on 'package.json' file:
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "testcafe": "^0.23.1-alpha.4"
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I just cloned this example: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/tree/master/examples/basic  . It works well when executed from bash.

Comment: This is my configuration on 'launch.json' file on vs code:         {
            "type": "node",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch test files with TestCafe",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/testcafe-example/test.js",
            "args": [
                "firefox",
                "${relativeFile}"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/testcafe-example"
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `launch.json` configuration specifies your test script in the `program` property:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/testcafe-example/test.js"
```

With this configuration, Visual Studio Code tries to execute your script as a regular Node.js script, and fails because Node.js doesn't support the `import` statement.

Specify main TestCafe script in this property as it's described in the [Debug in Visual Studio Code](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/debug-in-visual-studio-code.html) recipe:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe.js"
```

If you want to run a specific test script, replace the `"{relativePath}"` variable in the `"arguments"` property with the path to the test script:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe.js"
"args": [
    "firefox",
    "${workspaceRoot}/testcafe-example/test.js"
],
```